# Rules of backshift: will there be backshift or not here?

Tags: backshifting

I would like to explain the situation where I didn't notice my brother when he came home, and therefore didn't know when he got home.
I thought I should say like this:

> I didn't know when my brother had come home.

But I found another rule that if you are referring obvious facts, backshift wouldn't always appear.

> Mom wrote me that she will get home around seven.

and not always

> Mom wrote me that she would get home around seven.

Is it ordinary to say like this?

> I didn't know when my brother came home.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'obvious facts', but it depends on whether or not Mom has arrived home. (If she hasn't, _will_ is appropriate.)

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you very much for your information.  I wanted to mean by writing 'obvious facts,' 'things that are all natural for the speaker.'  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's perfectly fine.

> But I found another rule that if you are referring obvious facts, backshift wouldn't always appear.

Are you sure? Maybe you can provide the source of this? I doubt that this is true though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  So, can I say both "I didn't know when my brother came home" and "I didn't know when my brother had come home"?

Comment: Yup! @Nigutumok They are both fine and can be used!